# DuckDuckGo results scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I had a problem running my code, and found a perfect solution for this on StackOverflow. But, when I make necessary changes and run it, I get no output.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
import requests

r = requests.get('https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=test')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'result__url'}, href=True)

for link in results:
    url = link['href']
    o = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    d = urllib.parse.parse_qs(o.query)
    print(d['uddg'][0])
```

urlparse() for path components
" From this take the query string and pass it to `parse_qs()` to further process it. You can then extract the link using the `uddg` name."
This is supposed to be the first few results:

```
http://www.speedtest.net/
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/test
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/test
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/test
```

I get no output.
Output:

```
In [14]:
```

Comment: Could you try just running the script normally on the command line? ie. `python /path/to/script.py`

Comment: Nope, command line doesn't work too

Comment: My English is not good, so you want to get `link`, but the execution result is not there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting a `403`, thus you have no results. To fix this, add `headers`.

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
}

page = requests.get('https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=test', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').find_all("a", class_="result__url", href=True)

for link in soup:
    print(link['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/test
https://www.speedtest.net/
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/test
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/test
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/test
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test
https://www.tests.com/
http://speedtest.xfinity.com/
https://fast.com/
https://www.spectrum.com/internet/speed-test
https://projectstream.google.com/speedtest
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/test
http://www.act.org/content/act/en/products-and-services/the-act.html
...
```